# .sh files won't run, even after permission given

Tags: scripts

I have had a long history of not being able to run .sh files. I don't understand what the underlying problem is,(I'm a little bit new to Ubuntu/UNIX based systems). When I try to run certain .sh scripts I get the following error, accompanied by the Ubuntu Software Center starting up:

"The file "/home/user/Downloads/netbeans-8.1-cpp-linux-x86.sh" could not be opened."

As a clarification, I have been double clicking directly on the .sh file in the file system.

Comment: What was your command ?

Comment: Guessing: you are missing . in front of the command ;-) And yes we need 1. the actual command 2. a `ls -l` of the file.

Comment: Have you tried `bask /home/user/Downloads/netbeans-8.1-cpp-linux-x86.sh`?

Comment: And if that doesn't work, try `sudo chmod 755 /home/user/Downloads/netbeans-8.1-cpp-linux-x86.sh; bash /home/user/Downloads/netbeans-8.1-cpp-linux-x86.sh`.  You will be asked for your login password.

Comment: i was double clicking directly on the sh file. Is that where i went wrong?

Comment: What do you get if you run `xdg-mime query default $(mimetype -b /home/user/Downloads/netbeans-8.1-cpp-linux-x86.sh)` in a Terminal?

Comment: FlorianDiesch: 
I get   'application/x-shellscript'

Comment: @Rinzwind: It actually downloaded as a single .sh file. is that the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To install a `sh` script you need to type some commands. Double-clicking on it won't always work. So, first, open a terminal, then open your file manager and navigate to the location of your `sh` script.

1. Now, type the following command (edit the relevant parts) in your terminal:

   ```
   chmod a+x DRAG THE SH SCRIPT AND DROP IT HERE
   ```

**Note**: As pointed out by [kos](https://askubuntu.com/users/380067/kos), this is done, so that if at any time you wish to run it as below, then, you won't face any error.

```
./path/to/script
```

2. Next, type this:

   ```
   sh DRAG THE SH SCRIPT AND DROP IT HERE
   ```

If there are any errors such as `Permission Denied`, then run the script as `root`:

```
sudo sh DRAG THE SH SCRIPT AND DROP IT HERE
```

Comment: that did work, so thanks!

however, I am told the following error:
   /tmp/.nbi-5122111.tmp/_jvm/lib/i386/libawt_xawt.so: libXtst.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I was also told that i was using the wrong platform (it said x32 instead of x64), however, I redownloaded the program again, made sure I got the x64 bit system, and got the same error.

Comment: @patrickhuie19 - Did you install java previously?

Comment: If you're going to run the script with `sh /path/to/script.sh` it's unuseful to `chmod` it, `sh /path/to/script.sh` will run the script even if it's not executable. `chmod` is useful to run the script like so: `./path/to/script`

Comment: @kos - Thanks kos! I am new to linux! Still learning. Will edit my answer.

Comment: Since you're learning - in this case what you're suggesting is fine because the script is to be run in Dash, but be aware that `sh foo` will run `foo` in Dash regardless, i.e. *overriding a potential shebang*. I.e. a script meant to be run in Bash will be run in Dash (and maybe break). `./foo` instead will always read the shebang and the script will always be run in the right interpreter. It's worth nothing that if the script doesn't have a shebang at all the only way to run the script is specifying the interpreter in which it's to be run: `sh foo` :)

Comment: @patrickhuie19 Please ask another question for your follow-up issue.

Comment: @kos - Would you mind if I open a chat room with you and ask a few questions?

Comment: Nope, it's holidays, nothing to do. :) Even the general room is empty, I'm currently in there. Either drop by there or send me the link to the room.

Comment: @kos - http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33453/doubt-session-with-kos Please join.

Comment: @Raphael - I have installed the latest java version. I remember when I was trying to get eclipse installed properly, I had to do quite a bit of command line work, as well as when I was trying to install android studio. Does this remind you of a problem you've faced before?

Comment: @patrickhuie19 - Installing `eclipse` is the easiest of them all. Maybe one of the reason as to why I use it more frequently. And I haven't used Android Studio before so cannot help.

Answer (score 1):

There are two reasons why a simple script on linux may not execute:

1. The path is not correct.
   Unlike Windows, the current directory is **not** in the search path of the shell. So, to call a script in the current directory, you have to specify the current directory with the dot `.` before the name of the script: `./script.sh`. Alternatively you can specify the full path: `/home/user/script.sh`
2. The script file is missing. 
   Or it is under a *different path*. This the same as above.

You can execute scripts in two ways:

1. specify the name (with path) on the commandline. And - if the permissions are correct - the file will be run with the shell (if the [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) is correct)
2. use the shell command `sh` and specify the script as argument. Then, it's **not** necessary to specify the path, however the shell needs to be able to find the script. You would execute a script in the current directory like this: `sh script.sh`

Answer (score -4):

Try the command "chmod 777 " and then your file name. To run enter the name of your sh file with a ./ in front of it. Expempli gratia:
chmod 777 coolman.sh
./coolman.sh

Comment: No, 777 is never the answer.

Comment: No no never do this :)

Comment: @Rinzwind Unless you want it `rwx` by everyone :P